# Partial move of Vec of tuple

Tags: rust, move, move-semantics

I have a `Vec<(String, i64)>` and need to iterate over the `String`s and move them and then iterate over the `i64`s.

However, if I move the `String`s I have to store the `i64` again into another `Vec`:

```rust
let l: Vec<_> = l
    .into_iter()
    .map(|(string, int)| {
        drop(string);
        int
    })
    .collect();
                           
for i in l {
    process(i);
}
```

How can I iterate over the `String`s and `i64`s separately without incurring any additional performance overhead.

The only solution I can think of at the moment that will not cause additional operations is to store the `String`s and `i64`s separately.

Comment: you can just clone up what you need. Or *unzip* the `Vec<(s, int)>`

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: The idiomatic way is to [`unzip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.unzip).

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.take.html) while iterating over the `Vec` in a first pass to take ownership of the `String` element while putting a non-allocating `Default` in its place. This allows you to keep the `Vec` in its original form, so no extra container is required.

```
fn foo(mut inp: Vec<(String, i64)>) {
    // First pass over the Vec "extracts" the owned Strings, replacing the content
    // in the Vec by a non-allocating empty String, which is close to zero cost;
    // this leaves the Vec as is, so no intermediate representation is needed.
    for s in inp.iter_mut().map(|(s, _)| std::mem::take(s)) {
        // Process String
    }

    // Something happens

    // Second pass ignores the empty strings, processes the integers
    for i in inp.into_iter().map(|(_, i)| i) {
        // Process the integers
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware `String`s and `Vec`s allocated no memory by default. That's interesting: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.new

Answer (score 7):

If the type of the list can be changed to `Vec<Option<String>, i64>` from `Vec<String, i64>`, then you can try the following way.

```
fn main() {
    let mut l = Vec::new();
    l.push((Some("a".to_string()), 1i64));
    l.push((Some("b".to_string()), 2));
    l.push((Some("c".to_string()), 3));
    l.push((Some("d".to_string()), 4));
    
    l.iter_mut().for_each(|(s, _)| {
        if let Some(x) = s.take() { 
            println!("Processing string: {}", x);
        }
    });

    l.iter().for_each(|(_, i)| {
        println!("Processing int: {}", i);
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f36b6c0b8d417808cb100259a60b3af1)

Comment: Note that there is essentially zero overhead in this solution, not even for storage space, since `size_of::<String>() == size_of::<Option<String>>()`.

Comment: (You could make it _literally_ zero overhead by also eliminating the `if` using unsafe code and `unwrap_unchecked()`, but don't.)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`unzip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.unzip) to separate them:

```rust
fn main(){
    let original = vec![("a", 1), ("b", 2)];
    let (s, i): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = original.into_iter().unzip();
                           
    for a in s {
        println!("{}", a);
    }
    
    for b in i {
        println!("{}", b);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1439dac9384efe108b29dfbcdf35e9ae)

Comment: The OP asked "How can I iterate over the `String`s and `i64`s separately without incurring any additional performance overhead?" This solution allocates _two_ new containers instead of the single one in the original code, so I don't think it's much of an improvement towards the OP's goal.